# Merge Starter and Standard Edition?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just upgraded my starter edition account and now I have two versions of WoW (WoW1 and WoW2). WoW1 is the Starter Edition and WoW2 is the Standard Edition (Mists of Pandaria).

The characters I created in the starter edition are not available in the standard edition.

Is there any way to fix this? Or did I just pay to delete my characters?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Maybe it's just a matter of time for the server to update, but just to be safe, I'd contact customer support.

Comment: Crap, it did say something may take up to 72 hours. Maybe that was it. Thanks

Comment: The same thing happened to me - I talked to support, they told me to just use the second account... However, in my case my characters **were** available in the new account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you purchased WoW you accidentally created a new account rather than upgrading your existing account.

This does happen from time to time, and Blizzard can sort this out. Just open a support request for a phone callback and explain the situation.